# Are CardView and RecyclerView material design views?

Tags: android, material-design

I was just wondering whether they are really MD views because their names are
like 
android.support.v7.widget.CardView.

Is there a different package name for CardView when it comes to 5.0 and above versions (something like android.MaterialDesign.CardView)?

Comment: simply use android.support.v7.widget.CardView... only 20% have API 5.0+ , so... 80% others need the support library.

Comment: Is there something different from android.support.v7.widget.CardView for the 20%?

Comment: nope... even official documentation tells you to use support: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
```

Yes,they are and to use them into your app you would need to add these dependencies into your gradle file.

Recycler View

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Card View

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_custom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/custom_event_name"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:gravity="bottom|end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

CardView is basically a helper widget included in the support library. Even in Android 5.0 and above, you have to use android.support.v7.widget.CardView. However, there are differences in how this widget draws itself, in 5.0 and above.

From the official documentation:

> A FrameLayout with a rounded corner background and shadow.
>
> CardView uses elevation property on L for shadows and falls back to a
>   custom shadow implementation on older platforms.
>
> Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms
>   before L, CardView does not clip its children that intersect with
>   rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to avoid such intersection
>   (See setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean) to change this behavior).
>
> Before L, CardView adds padding to its content and draws shadows to
>   that area. This padding amount is equal to maxCardElevation + (1 -
>   cos45) * cornerRadius on the sides and maxCardElevation * 1.5 + (1 -
>   cos45) * cornerRadius on top and bottom.

See [Android Developers - CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) for more information.